# Ada-mode -- can't build gpr_query

Tags: programming

I'm using the ada-mode 5.2.1, gnat GPL 2017. I've built and installed gnatcoll successfully.

However, when I try to build gpr_query, I get  the following error:

```
$ gprbuild -p -P gpr_query.gpr                         
gprbuild: raised SYSTEM.ASSERTIONS.ASSERT_FAILURE : gpr-tree.adb:1246
[/opt/gnatGPL/bin/gprbuild]
System.Assertions.Raise_Assert_Failure at s-assert.adb:46
Gpr.Tree.Location_Of at gpr-tree.adb:1246
Gpr.Proc.Expression at gpr-proc.adb:616
Gpr.Proc.Expression at gpr-proc.adb:747
Gpr.Proc.Process_Declarative_Items at gpr-proc.adb:2406
Gpr.Proc.Recursive_Process at gpr-proc.adb:3276
Gpr.Proc.Process_Project_Tree_Phase_1 at gpr-proc.adb:2681
Gpr.Conf.Parse_Project_And_Apply_Config at gpr-conf.adb:1746
Gprbuild.Main at gprbuild-main.adb:2404
Main at b__gprbuild-main.adb:907
[/lib64/libc.so.6]
0x7fa2de9c4c03
[/opt/gnatGPL/bin/gprbuild]
0x000000000041279F at ???
```

I'm a bit stuck here. At first I couldn't get anywhere with gpr_query because of missing gnatcoll files in the GPL 2017 distro of Ada, but once I pointed the gpr file at the up-to-date version of gnatcoll, it built as far as the above error. If anyone could help, or if this is not relevant here and would be better on an ada forum then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The 5.3.1 release of GNU ELPA ada-mode supports GNAT GPL 2017 - see https://www.nongnu.org/ada-mode/

Also, the best place to get help on ada-mode is the ada-mode mailing list, also mentioned on the above web page.